# How to pivot values of timeindex

Tags: python

How can I pivot the minute data by keeping the day and hour data as it is?

input

```
,value
2024-07-07 03:00:00,-0.1
2024-07-07 03:15:00,-0.2
2024-07-07 03:30:00,-0.3
2024-07-07 04:00:00,-0.3
2024-07-07 04:15:00,-0.4
2024-07-07 04:30:00,-0.5
```

output

```
,0,15,30,
2024-07-07 03:00:00,-0.1,-0.2,-0.3
2024-07-07 04:00:00,-0.3,-0.4,-0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
out = (    
    df
    .assign(hour=df.index.floor('h'), minute=df.index.minute)
    .pivot_table(index='hour', columns='minute', values='value')
)
```

Note: make sure your index is a `DatetimeIndex` to start with. Using your data as example, here is a quick way to build the correct original `df`:

```
from io import StringIO

txt = """,value
2024-07-07 03:00:00,-0.1
2024-07-07 03:15:00,-0.2
2024-07-07 03:30:00,-0.3
2024-07-07 04:00:00,-0.3
2024-07-07 04:15:00,-0.4
2024-07-07 04:30:00,-0.5
"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(txt), parse_dates=[0], index_col=0)
```